# Error set selected value in selectbox after use append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropbox

```
<select name="product">
<option value="">Select a product</option>
<option value="1">iPhone</option>
</select>
```

And my script

```
$('select[name=product]').append("<option value='2'>Samsung</option>").prop('selected', true);
```

This is my result

```
<select name="product">
<option value="">Select a product</option>
<option value="1">iPhone</option>
<option value="2">Samsung</option>
</select>
```

How to fix it

```
<select name="product">
<option value="">Select a product</option>
<option value="1">iPhone</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Samsung</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier by adding `selected` attribute directly :

```
$('select[name=product]').append("<option value='2' selected>Samsung</option>");
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/pb5v6fnc/)**

Answer (score 0):

jQuery chaining returns the initial `select` object, but not an appended `option`.

Your code does the same as:

```
var o = $('select[name=product]');
o.append('<option/>');
o.prop('selected', true); // not on option, but on select
```

Change your syntax to the following:

```
$("<option value='2'>Samsung</option>")
    .appendTo('select[name=product]')
    .prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the selected property of the option.

Try?

```
$('select[name=product]').append("<option value='2' selected=SELECTED>Samsung</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. You can do that like this.

```
$('select[name=product]').append("<option value='2'>Samsung</option>");
$('select[name=product] option:last').attr('selected', 'selected');
```